# Importing Views

Tags: python, flask, python-import

**My app layout**

```
my_app
    __init__.py 
    my_app
        __init__.py
        startup
            create_app.py
            create_users.py
            common_settings.py
        core
            models.py
            views.py
```

**Inner __init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)           # The WSGI compliant web application object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)            # Setup Flask-SQLAlchemy
manager = Manager(app)          # Setup Flask-Script

from my_app.startup.create_app import create_app
create_app()
```

**create_app.py**

```
from native_linguist_server import app, db

@app.before_first_request
def initialize_app_on_first_request():
    """ Create users and roles tables on first HTTP request """
    from .create_users import create_users
    create_users()

def create_app(extra_config_settings={}):   

    app.config.from_envvar('ENV_SETTINGS_FILE')          

    # Load all blueprints with their manager commands, models and views
    from my_app import core                                                     

    return app
```

When I run my app like this and try to load a `view` in my browser, I get a `404` error.

However if I change:

```
from my_app import core
```

to

```
from my_app.core import views
```

it works fine.

Could someone please explain to me the difference between these two calls? I would have thought `from my_app import core` would also import `views.py` and hence there wouldn't be an issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from my_app import core
```

will load and execute `my_app/core/__init__.py` (if it exists). You will then have access to any identifiers defined inside or imported into `__init__.py`.

```
from my_app.core import views
```

will load and execute `my_app/core/views.py`. You'll then have access to any identifiers defined inside or imported into `views.py`.

To get the behavior you're expecting, you'll need to import `views` inside `__init__.py`:

```
from . import views
```